# Is there a way to trigger lambda only after multiple files have uploaded in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

A user uploads multiple files into my S3 bucket with the current day as prefix for all the files. I need to trigger a lambda function only after I have received all the files under the prefix. How can I do that?.

Comment: Please explain how "have received all the files under the prefix" can be identified. Do you upload a flag file that marks the end of all file uploads? Does the last file has a specific identifier? You can use S3 trigger to invoke a lambda function within which you can check such conditions.

Comment: Basically it is a very huge file and the user inserts in multiple parts, there is no identifier for the last part. It is also not fixed that only fixed number of parts will be inserted under the prefix.

Comment: Are they uploading a single file to S3 using multi-part upload, and you want to get a trigger when all parts have been uploaded? Or are they splitting the file into separate smaller files on the client-side and uploading them separately to S3?

Comment: They should be doing it the second way.

Comment: Then how do you know when they are done? How do you know, from looking at all the files present in S3, when it is time to start the batch job?

Comment: An update, the file count is known

Comment: What does that mean, "an update, the file count is known"? I previously answered that you could track the count with DynamoDB atomic counters, but you said the count was variable so that wouldn't work. Please provide enough information if you want us to be able to give an answer.

Comment: The scenario in the earlier case was the number of files we were getting were not fixed and varied. But we could ask for a way to send files in fixed number. That was my update. Your previous idea will fit in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a DynamoDb table to keep track of the uploaded parts. You should use a HASH key to store the *prefix* of the files, or something like that. Another attribute could be a count of parts.

On each part uploaded, a lambda will be called and it will update the record at the table in this way:

1. Read the record.
2. If the record does not exist, create it, with count = 1, using a conditional expression to create only if the record still not exists. This is to avoid one lambda overriding another.

   - If error, back to 1.
3. If the record exists, update it incrementing the count with the conditional expression to update only if the count is equal the count read on 1.

   - If error, back to 1.
4. When you reach the expected count, invoke the lambda to process it.